# Print Azure AD SSO signed-in user details within flask app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-authentication

Having Azure AD Single-sign-on enabled in single-tenant (SSO) in a docker web-app with flask app, **I am trying to fetch username of currently signed-in user** within my python flask application hosted through a docker.

I have used app-registration to authenticate web-app-service in single-tenant using https://*{url}*/.auth/login/aad/callback, and the app-service hosts a standalone docker image in the *{url}*.

Within the app, I need to fetch signed-in user's username to print out and log.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? We have the same question